# Serialize @JsonIgnore-d field

Tags: java, jackson

I have class with `@JsonIgnore-d` field:

```
public class MyClass {
    ...
    @JsonIgnore
    private SomeType myfield;
    ...
    // getters & setters
}
```

Is it possible to configure `ObjectWriter` so that it includes `myfield` during serialization even though being ingored?
Rationale: MyClass is serialized in many places and only in single specific one I want to have `myfield`.

Comment: I think you should need a custom serializer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is possible to configure `ObjectMapper` to disable a JsonIgnore function. Following are some possible solution you can try with:

**1.
Disable JsonIgnore function for a particular annotated field.**

You can create a custom JsonIgnore annotation and a custom `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` to remove the annotation from mapper context. 
Following are the ideas:

Annotate `@MyJsonIgnore` to the fields that should be ignored while serialization:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
public class MyClass {

    @MyJsonIgnore
    private SomeType myField;

}
```

`@MyJsonIgnore` is a simple custom annotation that wrap `@JsonIgnore`:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@JacksonAnnotationsInside
@JsonIgnore
public @interface MyJsonIgnore {
}
```

A custom `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` is implemented to remove  `@MyJsonIgnore` from mapper context:

```
public class DisablingMyJsonIgnoreIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {

@Override
public boolean isAnnotationBundle(final Annotation ann) {
    if (ann.annotationType().equals(MyJsonIgnore.class)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return super.isAnnotationBundle(ann);
    }
}
```

After that, you can set the introspector on a `ObjectMapper` during configuration:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new DisablingMyJsonIgnoreIntrospector());
```

It results that the fields annotated with `@MyJsonIgnore` can be marshaled properly.

**2.
Disable JsonIgnore function for the mapper**

Your can create a custom `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` and override `hasIgnoreMarker` method to always return `false`:

```
public static class DisablingJsonIgnoreIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {

    @Override
    public boolean hasIgnoreMarker(final AnnotatedMember m) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

`hasIgnoreMarker` is to check whether there is annotation to ignore json property. Return `false` will disable the JsonIngore function.

**3.
Disable all annotations and specify what kinds of properties are auto-detected for a given `ObjectMapper`:**

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.disable(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS);
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
```

This simply disable all annotations.

Hope this can help.

Comment: If I could I would give you 100 upvotes, great answer.

Comment: Any thoughts as to why using the custom annotation you give in option 1 with a default `ObjectMapper` still serializes fields annotated with that annotation?

Comment: good answer, I would add that in my case I had some other configuration changes and needed to call the setAnnotationIntrospector before the others.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the 1st solution ! it works very well!

Comment: The second alternative is wonderfull! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

One more option is to use the [AnnotationIntrospector.nopInstance()](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/AnnotationIntrospector.html#nopInstance--) if you want to avoid all Jackson's annotations in your pojo including @JsonIgnore e.g.

```
JsonMapper.builder().annotationIntrospector(AnnotationIntrospector.nopInstance()).build()...
```

or

```
new ObjectMapper().setAnnotationIntrospector(AnnotationIntrospector.nopInstance())...
```