# Reading @JsonIgnore field when using JacksonRabbit

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class as follows:

```
public class AlarmInfo {
   private UUID alarmUuid;
   private Object alarmInfoInJSON;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "alarm_uuid")
   public UUID getAlarmUuid() {
    return alarmUuid;
   }

   @JsonIgnore
   @Column(name = "alarm_info_json")
   public Object getAlarmInfoInJSON() {
    return alarmInfoInJSON;
   }
}
```

While converting the above AlarmInfo into String using Jackson Rabbit I can't read the alarmInfoInJSON as it is annotated with @JsonIgnore.

I am converting the AlarmInfo into the String as follows:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String alarmInfoJSON = mapper.writeValueAsString(alarmInfo);
```

However, I need to read alarmInfoInJSON . I can't change the original source code. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Couldn't you simply extend the class? I am guessing that other clients of this API won't be writing the `alarmInfoInJSON` anyway right?

Comment: I found the answer to the question over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38208692/serialize-jsonignore-d-field